# ts-node pass options to node

Tags: node.js, typescript, ts-node

Is there a way to pass options to node when invoking ts-node? I am trying to use an experimental feature in node and it would be swell if it would work with ts-node.

This is currently what I am doing:

```
ts-node ./src/utils/repl.ts -- --experimental-repl-await
```

Comment: [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54695790/157247), which is currently the accepted one, was wrong. [Sam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58667373/157247) is correct. I suggest switching the accepted mark to that answer (if you do, please ping me so I can delete the wrong one -- I can't delete it while it's accepted).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I got it to work this way:

```
node --experimental-repl-await -r ts-node/register ./src/utils/repl.ts
```

From the [`ts-node` documentation](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#programmatic):

> Note: If you need to use advanced node.js CLI arguments (e.g. `--inspect`), use them with `node -r ts-node/register` instead of the `ts-node` CLI.

---

Another way to do it is to use the `NODE_OPTIONS` environment variable. For instance, in a *nix-style shell:

```
NODE_OPTIONS=--experimental-repl-await ts-node ./src/utils/repl.ts
```

Comment: I don't get it. where do these go?