# Using `--max-http-header-size` option for ts-node

Tags: node.js, typescript, ts-node

Couldn't use `ts-node` with `--max-http-header-size 15000`.
I can use it with `node`, but there is no such option for `ts-node`

Comment: Would this work - https://stackoverflow.com/a/58667373/6453080 ?

Comment: @thanatonian2311 Post you answer, I'll tick it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
node --max-http-header-size 15000 -r ts-node/register <FILE>.ts
```